# udev 70-persistent-net.rules behavior change

Tags: 14.04, udev, interface

I currently manage over 30 nodes of Ubuntu, some are desktops, some are servers with version 14.04. Some node have `70-persistent-net.rules` file which auto generated by `udev.d`, some node don't have that file.

I did try `udevadm trigger` on some node which missing `70-persistent-net.rules` file, it did not generate at all.

So what's the deal here?

Comment: You can create your rules manually e.g. create a file `60-my-net.rules` and put the rules in the file..

Comment: Yes, things have been changing in this area. There will be differences between desktops, servers, and machines that have been upgraded from previous versions of Ubuntu. Does [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/628217/use-of-predictable-network-interface-names-with-alternate-kernels) help?

Comment: I mean, on Redhat/CentOS for example, when new NIC introduce on OS, new line will be written on 70-persistent-net.rules. Is there have a way to do this on Ubuntu?