# Predict network interfaces names in Wily/Xenial

Tags: networking, udev

I usually install systems with debootstrap. As part of the script, I add the interface `eth0` to `/etc/network/interfaces`.

But with Wily changing to persistent network interfaces, this doesn't work anymore, since, while it may be persistent, the name is also unpredictable (e.g. something like `enp0s3`).

How should I adjust? Is there any way to know what the interface name will be? To deactivate persistent names? Or is the only solution to defer that configuration to the first boot, for instance by using a systemd oneshot service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in my opinion, this stuff is a little inconsistent.
I now use the following line in grub:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="net.ifnames=1 biosdevname=0"
```

and things are the way they used to be (although I haven't tried it in Wily). See [also](https://askubuntu.com/questions/628217/use-of-predictable-network-interface-names-with-alternate-kernels).

Comment: Seems it does not work on Wily.