# Why eth0 became enp6s0, first install Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, udev

help please

```
_enp6s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 18:67:b0:db:c8:a8  
          inet addr:192.168.1.9  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)_
```

Comment: see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/628217/use-of-predictable-network-interface-names-with-alternate-kernels).

Answer (score 3):

From v197 systemd/udev will assign names in new format according to location of the connector of the hardware due security reasons. There are also several **Naming Schemes Hierarchy**, for example by BIOS provided PCI Express hotplug slot index numbers, by interface's MAC address

[Predictable Network Interface Names](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/)

You can view thous rules in:

```
vi /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

To migrate to old-style rules you use can this guide: [How to change network interface names permanently in Linux](http://ask.xmodulo.com/change-network-interface-names-permanently-linux.html)