# Changing network device name of a nfsroot used device

Tags: networking, kernel, udev, nfs, pxe

So to the context, I have a couple of machines starting up via an pxeboot that use an nfs share as their root.

Being able to use it you can/have to specify an device name in the pxelinux.cfg which you want to use for that boot.

Now I know that renaming of the devices would work with adding the `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` and adding content like this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", NAME="mynewname"
```

It als works for all devices besides that one device that you have to leave in the `/etc/network/interfaces` on manually like this:

```
iface enp8s0f2 inet manual
```

So the system doesn't try to restart the device and while doing it crash the system.

However now while trying around with renaming the device names I noticed it's also not possible (at least I couldn't find an obvious way) of renaming this used device. I'm assuming it's because the system is blocked by the loaded kernel to restart the device that is used as an nfsroot.

Now my question would be, is there a way to rename it?

Like adjusting the name during the boot (so before the nfs mount happens) and not afterwards, via an append command or adjusting the kernel used for booting?

Comment: Check this post which could be a duplicate https://askubuntu.com/q/628217/26246 . You may need to update the RAM disk FS which is used by Linux kernel before mounting the main root FS.